# Limits of getProgramAccounts?

Tags: getprogramaccounts

The official documentation does not mention the limits of `getProgramAccounts`, just that we should not abuse it. Can I get 50 accounts with 500 bytes each ? Or 5000 accounts with 500 bytes each ?

I would like to know the order of magnitude before building my app.

Answer (score 5):

After doing some researches, I found someone asking similar question in Solana discord.

> if program has 1m addresses how many i will have in rpc response

> You get the first 10MB

So it's limited to 10MB